# How to convert .rge files to Outlook 2010 format?

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, entourage

I have some Entourage archived files, of 5 different accounts, summing up to a total of approx 30 gb of mail data. I have accidently broken my mac and have purchased a windows system which came along MS Office 2010 subscription. I need to have access to these files, as I am in a new Windows environment, I don't know what to do. I have Outlook 2010, how can I access the entourage emails in my Outlook 2010 and can I access all the emails of all the 5 accounts???

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Entourage to PST Converter for the conversion, or all-in-one mail importer. It will convert the .rge to .pst.

Comment: $39 as of Jan 2015: http://www.stellaroutlooktools.com/scan/entourage-to-pst.php

Comment: This one's free: http://www.aid4mail.com/free-mbox-converter and wil probably stay that way.

Comment: Can you explain how a MBOX converter will help a Mac Entourage user where the file format is RGE and not MBOX? If they had Mac Entourage, they could export to MBOX, but it sounds like the Mac is not an easy option at this point.